# Optimistic UI updates with Firebase + React?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to do optimistic UI updates with Firebase (and React)?

I love this feature with Meteor but im looking to move to a back-end as a service as my back-end is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get real-time UI updates with firebase's **on child added** method.

```
 updateUI() {
 dbReference.on('child_added', snap => {
   /*
    *here you can update your redux/react state which will directly reflect 
    *to your UI
   */
   this.setState({
    data: snap.val().data  
   })
  }
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <span>{this.state.data.name}</span>
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: I double it @mi